# OSX UNIX ADD FILES PRIVILEGES TO SPECIFIC USER

Tags: macos, file-permissions

I have a deep directory called root,with a lot of folders,each folder is set with different permissions and there're  several users registered in the system.In the subfolders of root these users have different privileges and i don't want to change them,but i need to give to the admin user rwx permissions on all files and subdirectories in root.I can do that manually by using the get info menu with the second mouse button on each file that is still not with rwx permission for the admin user but that would require too much time.So the question is,how can i give permissions on a folder recursively to a specific user without changing files and folders owners and permissions for other users?is there no way to do something like

```
chmod -R  specific_user=rwx root_directory
```

?

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, login as Local Admin and at the Terminal, run:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a [username] -t user admin
```

Where [username] is the user you want to give admin permissions.

For example if the username was "User1", then the command would be:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a User1 -t user admin
```

http://community.centrify.com/t5/Centrify-Express/OSX-give-an-Ad-User-local-admin-permissions/td-p/8022